# Filtering search engine data

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with filtering information using a form,

Here is my code

```
$cooperation = Cooperation::with('user')->get();



$search_results = [];

$search = Input::get('q');
$category = Input::get('c');
$land = Input::get('l');

if(!empty($search || $category || $land)){



    $search_results = $cooperation;



    if (!empty($search)){
        $search_results = $search_results->where('title', 'like', '%'. $search .'%');

    }

    if (!empty($category)){
        $search_results = $search_results->where('category', $category);
    }

    if (!empty($land)){
        $search_results = $search_results->where('land', $land);
    }

    $exist_s = true;
    $not_s = false;
    return view('cooperation.index', compact('cooperation', 'search_results', 'exist_s', 'not_s'));


}

else{

    $not_s = true;
    $exist_s = false;
    return view('cooperation.index', compact('cooperation', 'search_results', 'exist_s', 'not_s'));

}
```

After retrieving data from the form I am trying to filter through the array in sequence by each variable but nothing happens, the only thing that works is filtering in $ category but I do not know why the rest does not work.

I'm looking for a solution as to how to filter data efficiently, I could do it if () after if () but with more variables it would be a very inefficient solution.

If anyone has any idea in advance thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have an efficient search according to your requirements you can have following input variables:

```
$columns, $searchColumns, $search_operator, $search_input
```

`$columns` can be the columns through which you can order, `searchColumns` can be the columns through which you want to have search and `search_operator` as in `like`, `<`, `<=`, `in`, `>`, `>=` etc, you can even improvise with the `direction` as `asc` or `dsc` in values, so you can have something like this:

```
return $query
    ->orderBy($request->column, $request->direction)
    ->where(function($query) use ($request, $searchColumns) {
        if($request->has('search_input')) {
            for($x = 0, $l = count($searchColumns); $x < $l; $x++) {
                if($request->search_operator == 'in') {
                    $query->whereIn($searchColumns[$x], explode(',', $request->search_input));
                } else if($request->search_operator == 'like') {
                    $query->orWhere($searchColumns[$x], 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search_input.'%');
                }
                else {
                    $query->orWhere($searchColumns[$x], $this->operators[$request->search_operator], $request->search_input);
                }
            }
        }
    })
    ->paginate(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your request is not working. However, if you are looking for a generic way of filtering your results I believe a simple foreach loop with an array of your filters variables would do the trick :

```
$filters = []; //your variables such as category and land go in there

foreach ($filters as $column => $value){
    $search_results = $search_results->where($column, $value);
}
```